# Custom planner manager does not show planner parameters in MoveIt

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wrote a custom planner manager that loads my own path planner for MoveIt. So far, everything compiles and MoveIt is able to use my planner manager and load the custom path planner. However, even though the planner configurations/parameters get loaded to the parameter server, the Planner Parameter field remains unpopulated in MoveIt.

I searched online and no one seems to have had this issue before. What could be the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351163/custom-planner-manager-does-not-show-planner-parameters-in-moveit/) by [Wilkson](https://answers.ros.org/users/52686/wilkson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2020-05-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[SOLVED]

I needed to retrieve the settings from the parameter server and put them in config_settings_.There is also a method I needed to implement (setPlannerConfigurations) which sets the parameters in the GUI and push the changes to config_settings_.

---

Originally posted by [Wilkson](https://answers.ros.org/users/52686/wilkson/) with karma: 26 on 2020-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0